# How can a i detect a mysql changes?

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql

i'm looking for a way to detect when an sql statement is fired, which statement was it and which database was modified.
I'm looking for a way to catch this data everytime an sql statement is executed on a mysql server (Linux server/Ubuntu).

Thanks.

Comment: Potential approaches: emulate a replication slave, and/or read the binlog.

Answer (score 3):

How about with triggers?  I've built complex auditing systems with them before, and they're just great.

Comment: Is is posible to execute a PHP script with this trigger?

Comment: Triggers live inside the database and do database-y things.  It may be technically possible to call other code (C, perhaps), but I wouldn't recommend it for maintenance reasons.  If you want to do this in PHP, force all of your apps database calls through one module, and add your logging there.